# Blog/Forum webpage for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum, blogs

I am looking for a blog/forum type webpage for ASP.NET. I am using the MVC project so I need a page that I can use the content of my Master page and my Site.css style sheet. Maybe a control or application extension. Also a link to a page where there are more of these controls would be nice.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I think you may misunderstand about ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly this is an unsolicited recommendation, but for social networking in asp.net I found this book useful - [ASP.NET 3.5 Social Networking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194788)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want some style templates you can get some here: [mvc templates](http://www.asp.net/mvc/gallery/)

Otherwise you can use whatever template (google's full of them) and adjust it so it corresponds with the view.